# Are all hypothetical machine models for calculating runing time of an alogrithm same?

Tags: time-complexity

Im learning about time complexity analysis, and cant seem to figure how why do we consider a hypothetical machine that takes *1 unit* of time for arithemitic and logical instructions and *1 unit* of time to for assignment and return statements.

**Q)** why does it have to be 1 unit of time?

**Q)** Also is it upto to the analyzer to define such parameters for hypotheical machine models or is there some sort "standard/convention" used instead ?

Comment: You may get more responses if posted on stackoverflow's Computer Science equivalent (stack exchange is the overarching organisation for both): https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for feedback, I will post it there too.!

Comment: You don't.  I have never heard of this "1 unit of time" thing.  The point of time complexity analysis is not about any kind of absolute time measurement; it's to determine how much more time an algorithm will take as the input size grows.  That is, if the input doubles in size, does the algorithm roughly take twice as long?  Four times as long?